# Setting Up QUnit Testing Kotlin - dependency 'kotlin-test' was not found

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, kotlin, qunit

I've been setting up a Kotlin project to use Qunit for testing according to this blogpost: https://medium.com/@czuckie/experimenting-with-kotlin2js-and-qunit-gradle-ab2164af695 before hopefully implementing on my company's main software.

Uncaught Error: Error loading module 'myapp_test'. Its dependency 'kotlin-test' was not found. Please, check whether 'kotlin-test' is loaded prior to 'myapp_test'.

Is the error I get trying to run the tests. It's got me confused. It seems to me that 'kotlin-test' will have been loaded prior but I guess not? What am I missing? This is my build.gradle file...

```
group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle 
plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'
apply from: "kotlinjs.gradle"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two things wrong with your code:

1. The `testCompile` dependency was incorrect (note addition of "-js"):

   ```
   -   testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
   +   testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js:$kotlin_version"
   ```
2. And in the corresponding `test.html` the wrong path to the generated build file was used. You need `kotlin-test.js` **not** `kotlin-test-js.js`:

   ```
   -   <script type="text/javascript" src="build/classes/test/lib/kotlin-test-js.js"></script>
   +   <script type="text/javascript" src="build/classes/test/lib/kotlin-test.js"></script>
   ```

   [image]

❇️❇️

**Of lesser importance but good to note:**

With those modifications in place the gradle `clean`, `build` and `test` tasks worked but the `Test` (decorator?) in the `TwoNumbers.kt` test file being imported from `org.junit` is deprecated -- which gave a WARNING on build -- so replace:

```
    import org.junit.Test
```

with:

```
    import kotlin.test.Test
```

And you'll be right to go!

[image]

Finally, not that it makes much difference but I used `ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.71"` just to be current